# Mouse Pointer Blinks and Sometimes Disappears

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, multi-monitor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS with dual Monitor. I am unable to figure out the problem occurring with the mouse pointer.

The mouse pointer blinks and at times it disappears.
[image: System Details] [image: Dual Monitor]

Comment: Does it reappear when you move the mouse elsewhere? Do you also see a regular pattern when it "disappears" ?

Comment: No there isn't a pattern, it just disappears at times  and keeps blinking. For example when opening the filesystem window, the cursor follows the mouse movement but at some point it disappears but the movement is followed [ i.e. the folder's hover effects etc gets followed ]

Comment: Do you have a multi touch device or a tablet attached to your system?

Comment: None, just a dual monitor

Comment: And the same works fine in single monitor

Answer (score 0):

I am not using an external monitor, and my Ubuntu version is 18.04, but I too sometimes have my mouse cursor disappear. Wanting to avoid a reboot I tried changing screens with Ctrl-Alt-F7 followed by Ctrl-Alt-F1. This restored my cursor.

Answer (score -1):

Try to type this command in the console:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```